# Deploying to a Tomcat server using Aptana

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, aptana

I am very new to Aptana. I like it but I am having some issues.

Very simply: How do I deploy or "add" a web project to a tomcat server in Eclipse?

Also, if you can send me any beginner guides on this kind of development specifically (Deploying Aptana projects in Eclipse) it would be much appreciated.

So:

1. I know how to create a project and run the internal Aptana server to preview the page.
2. I do not know how to deploy it to a server other than the internal one.
3. I have looked around and I mostly find forms and sites saying use the "Run Web Deployment Wizard".
4. I do not understand how to use it (mostly because I am trying to deploy on a local tomcat server created using eclipse.
5. The "Deploy App" function is also confusing because I think I can get it to sync with a server but.... thats it.
6. The non-Aptana way seems very easy and straight forward:

   1. Create dynamic web project
   2. add to server using "Add and Remove" function
   3. done! access the page using a browser!
7. Umm should I try pure Java EE? I heard it might be easier because Aptana is "bloated and tries to be too many things while excelling at none"-Another form

   1. Slightly off topic but, opinions? also I am assuming that git works well with Java EE like it does with Aptana.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if i get it wrong but you could try the following:

```
In Aptana Studio select Window->Show View->Servers
```

this should open the server-tab on the bottom, where the console resides. 
Now you can add an external webserver by clicking the arrow left to the "add server"-button.

you should now be able to add the created custom-server as your projects deployment-server

http://screencast.com/t/pnqxrHu89 may be useful

Comment: Yes I can do that but I cannot "add" Aptana projects to the servers.